# chainerで画像を学習させようとすると、 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dot'がでます。

Tags: python, chainer

機械学習初学者です。Chainerを用いて固定サイズの画像を学習させるため、サンプルのimagenet内のtrain_imagenet.pyとalex.pyをもとにコードを書いたのですがエラーを吐きました。
以下、ソースコードとエラー文です。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Example code of learning a large scale convnet from ILSVRC2012 dataset.

Prerequisite: To run this example, crop the center of ILSVRC2012 training and
validation images, scale them to 256x256 and convert them to RGB, and make
two lists of space-separated CSV whose first column is full path to image and
second column is zero-origin label (this format is same as that used by Caffe's
ImageDataLayer).

"""
import argparse
import random

import numpy as np

import chainer
from chainer import training
from chainer.training import extensions

import alex
import googlenet
import googlenetbn
import nin
import resnet50

count = 0

class PreprocessedDataset(chainer.dataset.DatasetMixin):

    def __init__(self, path, root, mean, crop_size_x, crop_size_y, random=True):
        self.base = chainer.datasets.LabeledImageDataset(path, root)
        self.mean = mean.astype(np.float32)
        self.crop_size_x = crop_size_x
        self.crop_size_y = crop_size_y
        self.random = random
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.base)

    def get_example(self, i):
        global count
        #print(count)
        count = count+1
        # It reads the i-th image/label pair and return a preprocessed image.
        # It applies following preprocesses:
        #     - Cropping (random or center rectangular)
        #     - Random flip
        #     - Scaling to [0, 1] value
        #crop_size = self.crop_size
        crop_size_x = self.crop_size_x
        crop_size_y = self.crop_size_y

        image, label = self.base[i]
        _, h, w = image.shape
        print(_,h,w)

        #if h != crop_size_y:
        #image = image[:, 0:h, :]
        #if w != crop_size_x:
        image -= self.mean[:, 0:crop_size_y, 0:crop_size_x]
        image *= (1.0 / 255.0)  # Scale to [0, 1]
        return image, label                
        """
        if self.random:
            # Randomly crop a region and flip the image
            top = random.randint(0, h - crop_size_y - 1)
            left = random.randint(0, w - crop_size_x - 1)
            if random.randint(0, 1):
                image = image[:, :, ::-1]
        else:
            # Crop the center
            top = (h - crop_size_y) // 2
            left = (w - crop_size_x) // 2

        bottom = top + crop_size_y
        right = left + crop_size_x

        image = image[:, top:bottom, left:right]
        image -= self.mean[:, top:bottom, left:right]
        image *= (1.0 / 255.0)  # Scale to [0, 1]
        return image, label
        """

def main():
    archs = {
        'alex': alex.Alex,
        'alex_fp16': alex.AlexFp16,
        'googlenet': googlenet.GoogLeNet,
        'googlenetbn': googlenetbn.GoogLeNetBN,
        'googlenetbn_fp16': googlenetbn.GoogLeNetBNFp16,
        'nin': nin.NIN,
        'resnet50': resnet50.ResNet50,
        'resnext50': resnet50.ResNeXt50,
    }

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Learning convnet from ILSVRC2012 dataset')
    parser.add_argument('train', help='Path to training image-label list file')
    parser.add_argument('val', help='Path to validation image-label list file')
    parser.add_argument('--arch', '-a', choices=archs.keys(), default='nin',
                        help='Convnet architecture')
    parser.add_argument('--batchsize', '-B', type=int, default=32,
                        help='Learning minibatch size')
    parser.add_argument('--epoch', '-E', type=int, default=5,
                        help='Number of epochs to train')
    parser.add_argument('--gpu', '-g', type=int, default=0,
                        help='GPU ID (negative value indicates CPU')
    parser.add_argument('--initmodel',
                        help='Initialize the model from given file')
    parser.add_argument('--loaderjob', '-j', type=int,
                        help='Number of parallel data loading processes')
    parser.add_argument('--mean', '-m', default='mean.npy',
                        help='Mean file (computed by compute_mean.py)')
    parser.add_argument('--resume', '-r', default='',
                        help='Initialize the trainer from given file')
    parser.add_argument('--out', '-o', default='result',
                        help='Output directory')
    parser.add_argument('--root', '-R', default='images/',
                        help='Root directory path of image files')
    parser.add_argument('--val_batchsize', '-b', type=int, default=250,
                        help='Validation minibatch size')
    parser.add_argument('--test', action='store_true')
    parser.set_defaults(test=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Initialize the model to train
    model = archs[args.arch]()
    if args.initmodel:
        print('Load model from {}'.format(args.initmodel))
        chainer.serializers.load_npz(args.initmodel, model)
    if args.gpu >= 0:
        chainer.backends.cuda.get_device_from_id(
            args.gpu).use()  # Make the GPU current
        model.to_gpu()

    # Load the datasets and mean file
    mean = np.load(args.mean)
    train = PreprocessedDataset(args.train, args.root, mean, model.insize_x, model.insize_y)
    val = PreprocessedDataset(args.val, args.root, mean, model.insize_x,model.insize_y, False)
    # These iterators load the images with subprocesses running in parallel to
    # the training/validation.
    train_iter = chainer.iterators.MultiprocessIterator(
        train, args.batchsize, n_processes=args.loaderjob)
    val_iter = chainer.iterators.MultiprocessIterator(
        val, args.val_batchsize, repeat=False, n_processes=args.loaderjob)

    # Set up an optimizer
    optimizer = chainer.optimizers.MomentumSGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    optimizer.setup(model)

    # Set up a trainer
    updater = training.StandardUpdater(
        train_iter, optimizer, device=args.gpu)
    trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (args.epoch, 'epoch'), args.out)

    val_interval = (1 if args.test else 100000), 'iteration'
    log_interval = (1 if args.test else 1000), 'iteration'

    trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(val_iter, model, device=args.gpu),
                   trigger=val_interval)
    trainer.extend(extensions.dump_graph('main/loss'))
    trainer.extend(extensions.snapshot(), trigger=val_interval)
    trainer.extend(extensions.snapshot_object(
        model, 'model_iter_{.updater.iteration}'), trigger=val_interval)
    # Be careful to pass the interval directly to LogReport
    # (it determines when to emit log rather than when to read observations)
    trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport(trigger=log_interval))
    trainer.extend(extensions.observe_lr(), trigger=log_interval)
    trainer.extend(extensions.PlotReport(['main/accuracy', 'main/loss'], x_key='epoch', file_name='main.png'))
    trainer.extend(extensions.PlotReport(['validation/main/accuracy', 'validation/main/loss'], x_key='epoch', file_name='valid.png'))    
    trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport([
        'epoch', 'iteration', 'main/loss', 'validation/main/loss',
        'main/accuracy', 'validation/main/accuracy', 'lr'
    ]), trigger=log_interval)
    trainer.extend(extensions.ProgressBar(update_interval=10))

    if args.resume:
        chainer.serializers.load_npz(args.resume, trainer)

    trainer.run()

    chainer.serializers.save_npz('result/model_final', model)
    chainer.serializers.save_npz('result/optimizer_final', optimizer)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

エラー文

```
Exception in main training loop: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dot'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 306, in run
    update()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 160, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, *in_arrays)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 645, in update
    loss.backward(loss_scale=self._loss_scale)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 963, in backward
    self._backward_main(retain_grad, loss_scale)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 1092, in _backward_main
    target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py", line 80, in backward
    gx, = LinearGradData().apply((W, gy))
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py", line 112, in forward
    gx = gy.dot(W).astype(gy.dtype, copy=False)
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_imagenet.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_imagenet.py", line 179, in main
    trainer.run()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 320, in run
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 306, in run
    update()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 160, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, *in_arrays)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 645, in update
    loss.backward(loss_scale=self._loss_scale)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 963, in backward
    self._backward_main(retain_grad, loss_scale)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/variable.py", line 1092, in _backward_main
    target_input_indexes, out_grad, in_grad)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 548, in backward_accumulate
    gxs = self.backward(target_input_indexes, grad_outputs)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py", line 80, in backward
    gx, = LinearGradData().apply((W, gy))
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/function_node.py", line 258, in apply
    outputs = self.forward(in_data)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py", line 112, in forward
    gx = gy.dot(W).astype(gy.dtype, copy=False)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dot'
```

ソースコードはtrain_imagenet.pyを、画像をクリッピングせずにそのまま学習に入力できるように書き換えました。
エラーの原因がわかるかたがいましたらよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

入力部分になんらかの誤りがあるものかと思います。
エラーメッセージの意味は、NoneType(空のオブジェクト)に対して.dot (おそらくnumpy.dot) を呼び出せないということです

どのようなargument でコマンドを実行したのか記述して頂けると参考になります